# Rendering html in R shiny causes other shiny output disappeared

Tags: html, r, shiny

I'm adding a new functionality to an existing shiny app. It adds htmloutput to the shiny app. However, if it renders html first then other functionality that used to worked well becomes disappear(No data table shows up). It is normal if I run the functionality in a non-reactive matter.

R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

I was looking at the issue on shiny website and tried the tips of adding taglist, it didn't solve the problem.

Here is the reproducible code that work normally in non-interactive way. However, if it allows user to select variables and strata information in reactive setting, the weird issue mentioned above comes up.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

```
lib <- c('shiny','data.table','DT','survival','explore','finalfit')
sapply(lib,require,character.only=TRUE)


ui <-  fluidPage(
      sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        id='side_panel'
        ),
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel('explore',htmlOutput("explore")),
          tabPanel('down',DT::DTOutput("down")),
         )

        ) # end of mainPanel

      ))


server <- function(input, output) {

# render data table
output$down <-renderDT({
  df <- setDT(survival::pbc)
  tabonep <- print(CreateTableOne(vars = c("sex", "age"), strata = "trt", data = df))
  tablef <-as.data.frame(tabonep)
  setDT(tablef)
  DT::datatable(tablef)
})

# generate exploratory analysis report

getPage <- function() {
  df <- setDT(survival::pbc)
  expl <- df %>% report(target = 'trt',output_dir = tempdir())
  return(includeHTML(expl))
}

output$explore <-renderUI({getPage()})

} # end of server

shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, what is `tabexpall()` or `tablep()`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I added one simplified shiny app. that works. The more complicated reactive is not shown.